# Why am I getting ImportError: No module named _gdal for GDAL in python2.7 on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, gdal, amazon-linux-2

I followed [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/abelcallejo/e75eb93d73db6f163b076d0232fc7d7e) for installing GDAL 3.2.0 on a new AWS t3a.large EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2 for use in python2.7 programs. The install seems to have worked, but when using `from osgeo import gdal` in python I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _gdal
```

When I search for files _gdal* I get:

```
/tmp/gdal-3.2.0/swig/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo/_gdalconst.so
/tmp/gdal-3.2.0/swig/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo/_gdal.so
/tmp/gdal-3.2.0/swig/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo/_gdal_array.so
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdalconst.so
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal_array.so
```

Here's everything I did:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy
sudo yum install cpp.x86_64 sqlite-devel.x86_64 libtiff.x86_64 cmake3.x86_64 -y
cd /tmp
wget https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-6.1.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf proj-6.1.1.tar.gz
cd proj-6.1.1
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
wget https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.0/gdal-3.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf gdal-3.2.0.tar.gz
cd gdal-3.2.0
./configure --with-proj=/usr/local --with-python
sudo make
sudo make install
which gdalinfo; gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.2.0, released 2020/10/26
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  I needed to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`